# Cannot get file last modified time via PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell

What I tried to do is searching a directory to output file path, name, version and last modified time into a txt file.

My code as below:

```
    function Get-Version($filePath)
    {
       $name = @{Name="Name";Expression= {split-path -leaf $_.FileName}}
       $path = @{Name="Path";Expression= {split-path $_.FileName}}
       $time = @{Name="Last Modified"; Expression={Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime}}
       dir -recurse -path $filePath | % { if ($_.Name -match "(.*exe)$") {$_.VersionInfo} } | select $path, $name,$time, FileVersion
    }

    Get-Version('E:\PS test') >> "version_info.txt"
```

However the output txt has name, path and version, but no last modified time.

Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're returning the `.VersionInfo` property from your `ForEach-Object` (`%`) call, and `.LastWriteTime` is a property of the file object, not the version info. Have a look at this:

```
 function Get-Version($filePath)
{
   $name = @{Name="Name";Expression= {split-path -leaf $_.VersionInfo.FileName}}
   $path = @{Name="Path";Expression= {split-path $_.VersionInfo.FileName}}
   $time = @{Name="Last Modified"; Expression={Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime}}
   $version = @{Name="FileVersion"; Expression={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}
   dir -recurse -path $filePath | ? { $_.Name -match "(.*exe)$" } | select $path, $name,$time, $version
}
```

By Changing the defintiion of `$name` and `$path` to refer directly to the version info, you can operate on the original object. I also had `$version` to get at the `FileVersion` you were referring to in the select.

That makes the `ForEach-Object` redundant, since you'd only be passing along the input. Since you were only checking a condition in it anyway, easier to convert it to `Where-Object` (`?`).

Expanding your aliases makes it look like this:

```
function Get-Version($filePath)
{
    $name = @{Name="Name";Expression= {Split-Path -Leaf $_.VersionInfo.FileName}}
    $path = @{Name="Path";Expression= {Split-Path $_.VersionInfo.FileName}}
    $time = @{Name="Last Modified"; Expression={Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime}}
    $version = @{Name="FileVersion"; Expression={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "(.*exe)$" } | Select-Object $path, $name,$time, $version
}
```

However I should also point out that you can filter the file names directly in `dir` (`Get-ChildItem`), making the `Where-Object` superfluous too:

```
function Get-Version($filePath)
{
    $name = @{Name="Name";Expression= {Split-Path -Leaf $_.VersionInfo.FileName}}
    $path = @{Name="Path";Expression= {Split-Path $_.VersionInfo.FileName}}
    $time = @{Name="Last Modified"; Expression={Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime}}
    $version = @{Name="FileVersion"; Expression={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath -Filter *.exe | Select-Object $path, $name,$time, $version
}
```

And then based on your comment, I realized it can be simplified even more:

```
function Get-Version($filePath)
{
    $path = @{Name="Path";Expression= {$_.DirectoryName}}
    $time = @{Name="Last Modified"; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime}}
    $version = @{Name="FileVersion"; Expression={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath -Filter *.exe | Select-Object $path, Name,$time, $version
}
```

`$name` is not needed because the file object already has a property called `.Name` that has the file name.

`$path` can be simplified because `$_.DirectoryName` already has the path.

`$time` can be simplified because the `.LastWriteTime` property is already a `[DateTime]` so you don't need `Get-Date`.

The only reason you still need the name/expression hashes for those is to have the fields be named something other than the underlying property. If you don't care about that, you could do this:

```
function Get-Version($filePath)
{
    $version = @{Name="FileVersion"; Expression={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath -Filter *.exe | Select-Object DirectoryName, Name, LastWriteTime, $version
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Very detailed explanation , solved my issue and pointed out improvement, thanks a lot!

Comment: One more question, is there any diff if I use $_.VersionInfo.FileName or I use $_.FileName? My original version used $_.FileName and it did pass filename to me. From you case all the info are from $_.VersionInfo

Comment: @Windtalker if the original object had a `.FileName` property then it would work, but it doesn't. Instead, it has `.FullName` which would serve the same purpose. In fact, you can get rid of your `Split-Path` calls by using `$_.Name` for the `$name` expression and `$_.DirectoryName` for the `$path` expression. And actually now that I think of it there's more to simplify and it's too long for a comment. See my latest edit.